# Как показать экранную клавиатуру с открытой вкладкой со смайлами

Tags: java, android

Как можно по нажатию на какую-то `View` показать клавиатуру с открытой вкладкой со смайлами?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Показать встроенную клавиатуру с открытой вкладкой смайлов - нельзя. Используйте сторонние библиотеки.

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но, вроде, еще на разных версиях клавиатуры (например, на MIUI) разное количество emoji. Особенно на старых устройствах.

Comment: А не подскажите нормальную либу для смайлов, клавиатуры типа https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon/ и на ее основании, выглядят так себе!

Comment: @KirillStoianov Да много их. https://github.com/edsilfer/emoji-keyboard/

Comment: @Hombre да, я эту либу видел,  ее и хочу прикрутить к проекту, но не смог пока рзорбраться, как вместо ихней TelegramPanel сделать свою чисто на EmodjiEditText, так и не понял как вызвать клавиатуру с Emodji, вы делали что то подобное с этой либой?